# authentification angular js with symfony

Tags: javascript, angularjs, symfony, symfony1

I have make authentification in application with angular js when I use API rest developed with symfony 2 (fosrestbundle for example), 
how to make authentification (login and register) in angular js with api rest symfony
thanks adavanced my friends

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I was writing about that.
http://matkodjipalo.com/index.php/2016/07/11/symfony-rest-api-user-registration/
http://matkodjipalo.com/index.php/2016/08/10/symfony-rest-api-user-login/
http://matkodjipalo.com/index.php/2016/08/18/symfony-rest-api-token-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

setup the server side oauth mechanism using https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle

then implement it in angular ..